# Why doens't this HTML5 audio-specific javascript work in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html

I have the following HTML5 audio-specific javascript that's working great for me in all browsers except for IE9 (see code below). Does anyone have any idea why? And is there any way that I can re-write the script so that it also works in IE9?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].play();
        $("#message").text("Music started");
    })

    $("#pause-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $("#message").text("Music paused");
    })

    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
        $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
    })

    $("#mute-bt").click(function(){     

        if ($("#audio-player")[0].muted == true) {          
            $("#audio-player")[0].muted = false;
            $("#message").text("Music Un-Muted");           
        } else {        
            $("#audio-player")[0].muted = true;
            $("#message").text("Music Muted");          
        }           

    })  

})
```

**HTML:**

```
<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player">
    <source src="http://www.colorshoutconcepts.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/uf_orange_and_blue.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.colorshoutconcepts.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/uf_orange_and_blue.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
</audio>

<div id="message"></div>

<a id="play-bt" href="#">Play music</a> | <a id="pause-bt" href="#">Pause music</a> | <a id="stop-bt" href="#">Stop music</a> | <a id="mute-bt" href="#">Mute</a>
```

---

EDIT:   How am I even supposed to reply to this thread? I keep clicking on the "add comment" & "answer your question" links, .. but nothing happens.

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting javascript errors when I click on any of the links:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'play'

I'm specifying MP3 and OGG files -- both of which are supported audio formats, .. and IE9 just spits out those javascript errors.

---

SOLVED:  As it turns out, I had to add opening & closing HTML, HEAD, & BODY tags to the html document I was testing with.  In other words, .. it actually works fine in IE9 when I created the page as a proper HTML5 document.

Comment: As a developer, you should know that "does not work" always needs a precise qualification. Does IE crash? Is the website rendered? Does the audio play?

Comment: Please be more specific. Which of `play()`, `pause()` and `muted` is giving you trouble? What does the error console tell you?

Comment: Regardless of the issue getting your `play()` method to work - be weary of using `mp3` format audio on your site/app/game as you may be required to pay licensing fees of $2,500 http://www.scirra.com/blog/64/why-you-shouldnt-use-mp3-in-your-html5-games use OGG for browsers that support it, and fallback to AAC for IE.

Answer (score 3):

Mp3 does work, the problem that IE has is playing .wav and .ogg

Works in IE9 - Chrome - Safari and firefox

```
var snd = new Audio("/pop.mp3");
snd.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does support the `audio` tag, but you need to provide an audio stream that IE9 can decode. Try MP3 or AAC in MP4 container.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410106#_HTML5_video_audio

More source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ff975061.aspx

EDIT: Your edit tells me that you are using an MP3 audio stream. That should work. Please give some more information. Any error messages in the F12 console?